# QField Postgres export failure

Tags: postgis, qfield

When trying to use the export function, at the end of the process, there is a prompt to enter authentication for the DB.  This prompt cannot be interacted with and leaves QGIS effectively frozen.  The message on the prompt reads:

> could not connect to server:No such File or Directory
> Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

This message only arises after saving saving the project to the DB.  The DB in question is not local to the system, and it's not clear why it is attempting a socket connection instead of going through the port connection.

I have been able to reproduce this on multiple clients (Mac and Windows, haven't tried Linux) and across multiple versions of QGIS-LTR.  The QField plugin has also been reinstalled several times.